# Root cause of OpenSSL 'sys read':execution expired'

Tags: ruby, openssl

I'm curious how I can test where this error is coming from? Because it's a timeout error is it an error on the server I'm sending it to? Or is it my own OpenSSL?

This suddenly started happening with an app that was running well for the past few weeks.

```
client = HTTPClient.new
client.set_auth @url, API_USERNAME, API_PASSWORD
response = client.post @url, payload.to_json, {'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Accept'=>'application/json'}
```

Results in this:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9/openssl/buffering.rb:36:in `sysread': execution expired (Timeout::Error)
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9/openssl/buffering.rb:36:in `fill_rbuff'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9/openssl/buffering.rb:160:in `gets'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/httpclient-2.5.2/lib/httpclient/session.rb:352:in `gets'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/httpclient-2.5.2/lib/httpclient/session.rb:881:in `block in parse_header'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9/timeout.rb:58:in `timeout'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9/timeout.rb:89:in `timeout'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/httpclient-2.5.2/lib/httpclient/session.rb:877:in `parse_header'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/httpclient-2.5.2/lib/httpclient/session.rb:860:in `read_header'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/httpclient-2.5.2/lib/httpclient/session.rb:667:in `get_header'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/httpclient-2.5.2/lib/httpclient.rb:1202:in `do_get_header'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/httpclient-2.5.2/lib/httpclient.rb:1151:in `do_get_block'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/httpclient-2.5.2/lib/httpclient.rb:952:in `block in do_request'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/httpclient-2.5.2/lib/httpclient.rb:1046:in `protect_keep_alive_disconnected'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/httpclient-2.5.2/lib/httpclient.rb:951:in `do_request'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/httpclient-2.5.2/lib/httpclient.rb:813:in `request'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9/gems/httpclient-2.5.2/lib/httpclient.rb:713:in `post'
...
my app stack
```

I've tested it with empty submission but it still doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Running from my server to the other:

```
echo "" | openssl s_client -showcerts -status -verify 0 \
        -connect some_site.com:443 2>&1 | \
        egrep "Verify return|subject=/serial"
Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)
```

Comment: Try to open the `@url` in the browser and check if their certificate is still active and good.

Comment: The sites certification (clicking on the Lock beside the URL) is valid for a few more years.

Comment: Would that mean my cert is the problem? Or is there anything else I can check to narrow it down?

Comment: According to error message, there is someone who has self signed her cert. That's why openssl complains. If you trust that server, then you need to install that cert as trusted. But, usually, it is a bad idea. If you don't know who that is, it is better not to do that. That might be a man-in-the-middle *attack*.

Comment: Thanks! 
Does ti matter that it's self-signed by a reputable provider:

` 3 s:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root`
`   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root`

Comment: That's the thing, if you consider issuer a reputable provider and willing to trust it, then you may decide to trust it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109736/discussion-between-jqwierdy-and-uzbekjon).